# WHERE CONTAINS does not return data

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

Contains and Like does not work with my variable.

I tried using the keywords `LIKE` and `CONTAINS`

```
@ItemSupplied nvarchar (50)
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    SELECT [Name]
    FROM Suppliers
    where CONTAINS(ItemSupplied, @ItemSupplied)
    order by [Name];
end
```

I also tried

```
@ItemSupplied nvarchar (50)
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    SELECT [Name]
    FROM Suppliers
    where ItemSupplied LIKE @ItemSupplied
    order by [Name];
end
```

I want too get the name of suppliers who supply a specific item even though they supply other items as well.

Comment: Don't you need a % for LIKE?

Comment: Is `CONTAINS` even a valid MySQL construct? ....edit: Ah, MySQL != MSSQL; you should fix your tags. Also, you need to be more specific than "does not work".

Comment: where should i put the %

Comment: @RickalHamilton Read the documentation!!!

Comment: as far as i know i found it in some codes when i google search

Comment: @ Eric what documentation?

Comment: This code is for ms sql server, not mysql. Pls pay attention to the tags you are using, they can really mislead people!

Comment: sorry i thought there was just mysql oracle etc. i am looking for the correct syntax for  SQL SERVER

Comment: @RickalHamilton "What documentation?"  Documentation of how to use `LIKE`, where to put `%`.  SO helps people fix their code, but if you don't know how to write query, then you should read the documentation, (MSDN) in this case.

Comment: Also read this to learn how to ask proper question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results. We're just guessing at answers right now.

Comment: If you are trying to pass more than one item in the variable, then you'll need to us a `split function` for the variable.

Comment: Just in case you don't know - `CONTAINS` is used when you have a Full-Text Index set up on columns in the table. Without it you can't use that predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just tested this in MSSQL

```
   DECLARE @ItemSupplied nvarchar (50)

     SELECT [Name]
     FROM Suppliers 
     WHERE ItemSupplied LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@ItemSupplied)) + '%'
     ORDER BY [Name];
```

Comment: @ Ess Kay LOL i was looking for SQL SERVER code but after a slight tweek your code worked thanks a lot...

Comment: i am going to go ahead and assume LTRIM  means Left trim and RTRIM means Right trim???

Comment: yes, just in case you have trailing or preceding spaces. That for me usually gives the issue of no results, and hard to see a space. we want to just remove all spaces before and after the text

Answer (score 2):

If you want use like and a variable  you could use concat for build a valid like pattern

```
 SELECT [Name]
 FROM Suppliers 
 where ItemSupplied LIKE concat('%', @ItemSupplie, '%')
 order by [Name];
```

Comment: still returns nothing. ItemSupplied contains text "Meat, Egg" i want to select suppliers that supply egg.

Comment: check better  ..  because using concat you have a valid  like  .. be sure you have only 'egg' in var ..  Are you sure you have set the content of @itemSupplie with a valid value??

Comment: yes it gets set by a selection from a combobox, if i do WHERE Itemsupplied = @ItemSupplied i get the data for those with only one item so the variable works, however with the code you provided it works if it test the query with a static value but  not with the variable am not sure if i need to change something in my code

Comment: looking to your  code  ..  seems you have only declared the var but i don't see the assigment of a value ..